# python tkinter and mysql connectivity error

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, connectivity

So im trying to write a program for a school project related to python tkinter and mysql connection for a central hotel managment system and i just cant figure out a certain issue in my file.

Im bassically trying to use mid label as a variable and trying to have it present when mid has a value, but if it doesnt then it should just ignore the value of mid and input the rest of them in the mysql table:
This is the main program

```
import mysql.connector as pro
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as Messagebox
c= pro.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database="dbms")
m= c.cursor()
def add():
    gid=data.get()
    mid=data5.get();
    fname=data1.get();
    lname=data2.get();
    address=data3.get();
    contact=data4.get();
    c= pro.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database="dbms")
    m= c.cursor()
    if mid=="":
        gid=data.get()
        fname=data1.get();
        lname=data2.get();
        address=data3.get();
        contact=data4.get();
        c= pro.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database="dbms")
        m= c.cursor()
        m.execute("insert into guest values('"+ gid +"','"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"','"+ address +"','"+ contact +"')'")
        m.execute("commit");
        data.delete(0,'end')
        data1.delete(0,'end')
        data2.delete(0,'end')
        data3.delete(0,'end')
        data4.delete(0,'end')
        data5.delete(0,'end')
        Messagebox.showinfo("Insert Status","Inserted Successfully");
        c.close();
    else:
        gid=data.get()
        mid=data5.get();
        fname=data1.get();
        lname=data2.get();
        address=data3.get();
        contact=data4.get();
        c= pro.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database="dbms")
        m= c.cursor()
        m.execute("insert into guest values('"+ gid +"','"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"','"+ address +"','"+ contact +"','"+ mid +"')'")
        m.execute("commit");
        data.delete(0,'end')
        data1.delete(0,'end')
        data2.delete(0,'end')
        data3.delete(0,'end')
        data4.delete(0,'end')
        data5.delete(0,'end')
        Messagebox.showinfo("Insert Status","Inserted Successfully");c.close();
def update():
    gid=data.get()
    value=data6.get();
    if(guest=="" or value==""):
        Messagebox.showinfo("Update Status","All fields are required")
    else:
        c= pro.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", database="dbms")
        m= c.cursor()
        m.execute("update guest set status  ='"+ value +"' where =guest_id'"+ gid +"'")
        m.execute("commit");
        data.delete(0,'end')
        data1.delete(0,'end')
        data2.delete(0,'end')
        data3.delete(0,'end')
        Messagebox.showinfo("Update Status","Updated Successfully");
        c.close();

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("Guest")
a=tk.Label(root,text="Guest Data",font=("Impact",16))
a.place(x=20,y=10)

gid=tk.Label(root,text="Guest ID:- ", font=("Times New Roman",14))
gid.place(x=20,y=60)
fname=tk.Label(root,text="First Name:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
fname.place(x=20,y=100)
lname=tk.Label(root,text="Last Name:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
lname.place(x=20,y=140)
address=tk.Label(root,text="Address:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
address.place(x=20,y=180)
contact=tk.Label(root,text="Phone:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
contact.place(x=20,y=210)
mid=tk.Label(root,text="Member ID:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
mid.place(x=20,y=250)
value=tk.Label(root,text="Value:- ",font=("Times New Roman",14))
value.place(x=20,y=280)

data=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data.place(x=150,y=60)
data1=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data1.place(x=150,y=100)
data2=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data2.place(x=150,y=140)
data3=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data3.place(x=150,y=180)
data4=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data4.place(x=150,y=210)
data5=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data5.place(x=150,y=250)
data6=tk.Entry(root,font=("Arial",15))
data6.place(x=150,y=280)

add=tk.Button(root,text="Add New",font=("Arial",12),command=add)
add.place(x=290,y=310,width=80)
update=tk.Button(root,text="Update Existing",font=("Arial",12),command=update)
update.place(x=150,y=310)

root.mainloop()
```

and this is the error i keep getting;

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 611, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kabir\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\guesttk.py", line 23, in add
    m.execute("insert into guest values('"+ gid +"','"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"','"+ address +"','"+ contact +"')'")
  File "F:\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 330, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 619, in cmd_query
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1
```

Any help is appreciated
thanks in advance
(btw the name of the table is guest)

Comment: If you save the SQL in a variable and print it out, you will find that there is an extra single quote at the end.

Comment: Note that it is easier to construct the SQL using placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the final SQL statement in variable and print it out, you will find that there is an extra single-quote at the end of the statement:

```py
# dummy values for those variables:
gid = "1234"
fname = "hello"
lname = "world"
address = "address"
contact = "contact"
# save the SQL statement in a variable
sql = "insert into guest values('"+ gid +"','"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"','"+ address +"','"+ contact +"')'"
# print it out
print(sql)
```

and the output:

```
insert into guest values('1234','hello','world','address','contact')'
```

It is better to use *placeholders* in the SQL statement:

```py
m.execute("insert into guest values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (gid, fname, lname, address, contact))
```